# Ctrl + C does not work specifically when trying to run multiple instances of a C program

Tags: c, bash, shell, operating-system

I'm going through an open source textbook on operating systems, and this is one of the first code examples (filename is "cpu.c"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: cpu <string>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *str = argv[1];

    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run "./cpu 'A'" in a terminal, everything works fine and I can terminate it using Ctrl + C. However, when I run the code using

```
./cpu A & ./cpu B & ./cpu C & ./cpu D &
```

making multiple instances of the program run, and try using Ctrl + C, the code continues to run indefinitely. I have read online that Ctrl + Z can work, but it doesn't help. Is there a way to end the 4 programs running without closing the terminal? I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536556/ending-multiple-instances-of-a-c-program-at-once) but I don't believe it will help with my problem.

Comment: You can always open up *another* terminal and use `ps` and `kill` to locate and terminate them.

Comment: `./cpu A & ./cpu B & ./cpu C & ./cpu D &` is leaving a few competitors behind. _You_ are still in change though

Comment: Control-C affects the foreground process (i.e. the one controlling the terminal). Since the background process don't even see your input, they can not react. You can terminate background processes using `kill`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've run the 4 processes in the background, so the shell is still waiting for your input.  The processes, however, are not paying attention to the interrupt signal.

You can kill them with job numbers:

```
$ ./cpu A & ./cpu B & ./cpu C & ./cpu D &
[1] 9735
[2] 9736
[3] 9737
[4] 9738
$ kill %1 %3
[3] - Terminated               ./cpu A & ./cpu B & ./cpu C & ./cpu D &
[1]   Terminated               ./cpu A & ./cpu B & ./cpu C & ./cpu D &
$ kill %2 %4
[4] + Terminated               ./cpu A & ./cpu B & ./cpu C & ./cpu D &
[2] - Terminated               ./cpu A & ./cpu B & ./cpu C & ./cpu D &
$
```

I've suppressed the output from the 4 programs, of course.

Since you were given the PIDs of the processes, you could also use those with `kill`: `kill 9735 9736 9737 9738` would also have killed the four background processes.  The `kill` command sends the SIGTERM signal by default.

Answer (score 2):

> when I run the code using "./cpu A & ./cpu B & ./cpu C & ./cpu D &" making multiple instances of the program run, and try using Ctrl + C, the code continues to run infinitely. I have read online that Ctrl + Z can work, but it doesn't help.

The `&` terminating each of those commands tells the shell to run the command in the background.  The terminal does not send signal to background processes in response to you typing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Z.  Only the foreground process will receive such signals.

> Is there a way to end the 4 programs running without closing the terminal?

Since the programs will not terminate normally on account of their unbounded looping, they will only die if you kill them.  There are several ways you could do that, among them by

- looking up their process IDs with the `ps` command and then killing them with the `kill` command.
- one at a time, bringing them to the foreground via the `fg` command, where you can kill them with Ctrl+C.

The latter is the easier of the two.